# selecting rows of which the value of the variable is equal to certain vector

Tags: r, row, subset

I have a longitudinal data called `df` for more than 1000 people that looks like the following:

```
id  year    name    status  
1   1984    James   4   
1   1985    James   1   
2   1983    John    2   
2   1984    John    1   
3   1980    Amy     2   
3   1981    Amy     2   
4   1930    Jane    4   
4   1931    Jane    5
```

I'm trying to subset the data by certain `id`. For instance, I have a vector `dd` that consists of `id`s that I would like to subset:

```
dd<-c(1,3)
```

I've tried the following but it did not work, for instance:

```
subset<-subset(df, subset(df$id==dd))
```

or

```
subset<-subset(df, subset(unique(df$id))==dd))
```

or

```
subset<-df[which(unique(df$id)==dd),]
```

or I tried a for-loop

```
for (i in 1:2){
  subset<-subset(df, subset=(unique(df$id)==dd[i]))
}
```

Would there be a way to only select the rows with the `id`s that match the numbers in in the vector `dd`?

Comment: It's not a good idea to call your subset `subset` as that is the name of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%in%` and logical indexing:

```
df[df$id %in% dd,]
  id year  name status
1  1 1984 James      4
2  1 1985 James      1
5  3 1980   Amy      2
6  3 1981   Amy      2
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use *'[**dplyr**](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/)'* a new package (author: Hadley Wickham ) which provides a blazingly fast set of tools for efficiently manipulating datasets.

```
require(dplyr)

filter(df,id %in% dd )
  id year  name status

1  1 1984 James      4
2  1 1985 James      1
3  3 1980   Amy      2
4  3 1981   Amy      2
```